# Trait + Namespace, что не так?

Tags: phpstorm, namespace, traits

**Имеются Классы:**

```
/App/Catalog1/NameClass1.php  - с namespase App\Catalog1;

/App/Catalog2/NameClass2.php  - с namespase App\Catalog2;

/App/Catalog3/NameClass3.php  - с namespase App\Catalog3;
```

**Для них нужно подключить общий трейт:**

`/App/Common/CommonTrait.php` - с `namespase App\Common;`

**При попытке подключить общий трейт в классы, например:**

`namespase App\Class1;
use App\Common;
class NameClass1
{
    use CommonTrait;
}`

- не найдено и всё тут, причём PHPStorm - всё находит и **ни какой ошибки не высвечивает.**
- Следующий вариант - тоже не пашет:

`namespase App\Class1;
class NameClass1
{
    use \App\Common\CommonTrait;
}`

Автозагрузчик согласно PSR-4 и всё остальное подключается правильно.
Но этот трейт не подключить ни как.

Кто знает, что не так делаю?

Comment: используется автозагрузчик composer?

Comment: да, для всего приложения и сторонних библиотек, но именно для данных классов (самописных) он не нужен, поэтому пока его за комментировал.

Comment: Тогда мне нужно увидеть тот автозагрузчик, который реально загружает файлы

Comment: Да он практически идентичен:
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ru/examples/#С-использованием-класса

Фишка в том ещё, что для другого набора классов другой трейт подключается и всё работает как надо, то есть не в автозагрузчике дело.

Comment: и все же, покажите оригинальный код загрузчика и его конфигурацию

Comment: Ни как :(. Даже когда удалил все комментарии в коде класса, пишет, на 1500 символов больше, чем здесь можно разместить.

Comment: в таком случае могу только посоветовать использовать composer (никаких особых плюсов его отключение вам все равно не даст)